# Place image to the right of multiple lines of text

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs: One div for multi-line text and another for an image that is to the right of the first div.

The width of the image is not fixed - it is controlled by a user defined parameter.

```
<div>
  <div class="inline_div">
    multi line text...
  </div>

  <div class="picture">
    image...
  </div>
</div>


inline_div {
    display: inline-block;
}
. picture {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This works great for a single line of text. But when the text goes into multiple lines, the image gets placed below the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can float both `div`'s to left, and assign appropriate widths as required.

```css
.container {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.inline_div {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}
.picture {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inline_div">
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
  </div>

  <div class="picture">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, you could use `display: flex` with appropriate width distribution.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.inline_div {
  flex: 2;
}
.picture {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inline_div">
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
  </div>

  <div class="picture">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inline_div">
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
    multi line text...
  </div>

  <div class="picture">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that width of the image is not fixed. It is controlled by a user defined parameter.

Comment: You could use `flex` in that case. The right div will just expand if there is a need to. Try changing the image src to `https://placehold.id/250x250`. See the second snippet in my answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!